# How do I use Rails UserMailer method to access files saved with CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, amazon-web-services, download, carrierwave

I want to send an email to users at the same time they are downloading information through their phone. The pdf I'm trying to send is stored on AWS using CarrierWave. I'm not entirely sure how to access files from CarrierWave.

**Question #1) - Less Important** - 
One question is should I ask the server to pull down these files from AWS to send over email OR should I cache these files on the server as they are uploaded to AWS. The current purpose of storing files on AWS is so they can be pulled down to the iOS client(phone).

...Let's assume for now I'm trying the option of pulling down the file (pdf) from AWS to send over email. The command `File.read(@file)` in the code below won't work because I'm trying to pull down a file such as (*example* - @file = 'http://placecorgi.com/100/100.pdf') which is not a file but a file on a server.

**Questions #2) - More Important** - 
What do I need to change to pull down this file from AWS and send through UserMailer?

This is the UserMailer - I'm trying to fix the method `send_user_pages`. The method `welcome_email` works fine.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    attachments['mail.pdf'] = File.read('mail.pdf')
    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Welcome to App!')
  end

  def send_user_pages(user, pages_array)
    @user = user
    @pages_array = pages_array
    pages_array.each_with_index do |page, index|
      @file = "#{page.url}"
      attachments["user_pages_#{index}.pdf"] = File.read(@file)
    end
    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Your Pages')
  end
end
```

Here's my CarrierWave Setup...

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.test?
config.storage = :file
  else
config.storage = :fog

config.fog_credentials = {
  provider: 'AWS',
  aws_access_key_id: ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  aws_secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  region: 'us-west-1'
}

if Rails.env.production?
  config.fog_directory = ENV['AWS_BUCKET']
else
  config.fog_directory = 'q-local'
end
  end
end
```

Here's my CarrierWave Uploader...

```
class AssetUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def self.with_allowed_type(*types)
    klass = Class.new(self)

    klass.instance_eval do
      define_method :extension_white_list do
        types
      end
    end

    klass
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to provide a secured link to the aws file path in the email to the user to download the pdf. If thats the case, you can do it like this

```
    s3 = AWS::S3.new
    bucket = s3.buckets['your-bucket-name']
    # file path (change it to yours)
    relative_path = "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}.pdf"
    obj = bucket.objects[relative_path]
    # in this example, the download link will expire in 10 mins, probably you should remove it if you dont want
    s3_url = obj.url_for(:read, :secure => true, :expires => 10.minutes).to_s
```

And pass this `s3_url` to in the email message.